Ubuntu 24.04 freezes randomly
Have ryzen5 cpu, asus motherboard, 16gb memory.
Just installed Ubuntu 24.04, keeps freezing. Tried to change to Mate, it is a bit more stable, but still freezes now and then. Have same issues with 22.04.
What can I do?
I have seen this answer
Ubuntu 24.04 freezes randomly and does not recover without force shutdown
but i am a newbie, i dont know how to change grub parameters.
Thanks for your help.

When freezes the screen? Could be an issue with Wayland. I'm having the same thing with an Intel and it happens since I have installed 24.04.

This is a common problem that may be due to different reasons; probably the methods proposed here would solve your issue.
In case of unsuccess, upgrade your post by adding

the solutions you tried
your kernel version (write unamne -r in the terminal to see it)
your graphic card
your sudo journalctl output

This info is necessary to understand what's causing the crash.
I had the same problem (check this if you want), and I solved it by upgrading the Bios version. However, first of all, I suggest performing a memtest to be sure that your RAM works perfectly.
Anyway in case of doubts or problems, feel free to ask!
